# Getting system uptime in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am looking for a better way to retrieve a systems uptime. My current method works, but I feel like things can be done better.

```
def uptime_range
  days_up = `uptime | awk {'print$3'}`.chomp.to_i
  hours_up = `uptime | awk {'print$5'}`.delete(',').chomp
  seconds_up = time_to_seconds(days_up,hours_up)
  started = Time.now - seconds_up
  "#{started.strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M')}-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M')}"
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On linux systems you can open /proc/uptime and read seconds since the machine booted.

```
def started
   Time.now - IO.read('/proc/uptime').split[0].to_f
end
```

Edit: changed to_i to to_f.  With to_i, the value of started when displayed as a string or integer is more likely to vary, especially if the boot time was close to the middle of a second rather than at the beginning or end of a second.

Answer (score 4):

You could check the [sysinfo gem](https://github.com/delano/sysinfo/). It should give system-independent access to the uptime data.

Answer (score 0):

A rubygem called [linux_stat](https://github.com/Souravgoswami/linux_stat) can do that pretty well:

```
require 'linux_stat'

LinuxStat::OS.uptime
=> {:hour=>40, :minute=>46, :second=>19.75}
```

Code copied from [here](https://github.com/Souravgoswami/linux_stat#linuxstatos).

But if you don't feel like using another gem for this trivial task, you can do this:

```
uptime = IO.read('/proc/uptime').to_f
uptime_i = uptime.to_i

puts({
    hour: uptime_i / 3600,
    minute: uptime_i % 3600 / 60,
    second: uptime.%(3600).%(60).round(2)
})
```

Which prints:

```
{:hour=>0, :minute=>39, :second=>54.89}
```